# How to show a loop from function inside a class in a template?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a table with the values in "a" but the function is inside a class:

```
# Views.py
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'

    def get_graph_sales_year_month(self):
        data = []
        try:
            year = datetime.now().year
            for m in range(1, 13):
                total = Sale.objects.filter(date_joined__year=year, date_joined__month=m).aggregate(
                    r=Coalesce(Sum('iva'), 0)).get('r')
                data.append(float(total))
        except:
            pass
        return data

    # And I got a lot of others self functions


    def get_test(request):
    
        a = ['hola','chau','como','va']
        
        #return a
        return  render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'name': a})

# HTML template


<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><span>Date</span></th>            
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for i in name %}
          <tr>
            
            <td><span>{{i}}</span></td>

            
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          
         </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

I've tried this function (outside a class) in another template and it works:

```
def get_test(request):
    
    a = ['hola','chau','como','va']
    
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'name': a})
```

But I want that function inside the class because I call all the class at the URL.py:

```
path('dashboard/', DashboardView.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
```

I would like something like this:
[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I got a lot of self functions inside the class!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the context to the `get_context_data` method of the `TemplateView`. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview).

```
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['a'] = ['hola','chau','como','va']
        return context
```

Edit:
Also, check the `extra_context` way as recommended by Abdul. You can add some context as a class attribute or directly in the url declaration. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin).

As attribute:

```
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'
    extra_context = {'a': ['hola','chau','como','va']}
```

In the url:

```
path(
    'dashboard/',
    DashboardView.as_view(extra_context={'a': ['hola','chau','como','va']}),
    name='dashboard',
),
```

Comment: Also mention the `extra_context` attribute one can set on the class (if this extra context is not supposed to be dynamic). [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#contextmixin)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks, added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks, the I was missing the first part. It works. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do this staff in function based view, which is more simple in your case.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

path('dashboard/', get_test, name='dashboard'),

@login_required
def get_test(request):
    
    a = ['hola','chau','como','va']
    
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'name': a})
```

Comment: Thanks! but I've forgot to mention that I got anothers self functions inside the class. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the context data returned in a class based view
[TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) using   [get_context_data method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data)

something like this

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):
    
        template_name = "dashboard.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            a = ['hola','chau','como','va']
            context['name'] = a
            return context
```